# Use of 'of' between two nouns - and its translation into German

Tags: prepositions

What troubles me is the possible misunderstanding of the preposition of between two nouns (defining a part/portion vs. just separating the nouns).

Let's say a province of country X is called Bumba. In a report on that province, the English version would be:

> "In the southern province of Bumba, there were ...".

Correct so far? Because, if not, my whole question would break down. So, in (hastily translated) reports you might hear (I just did):

> "In der südlichen Provinz von Bumba ..."

suggesting that Bumba was part, and not the entirety, of that province.

And what about the translation into German of "*the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Ireland*", which should perhaps go without the "*von*"? In the same way as the "*German capital of Berlin*" is "*die deutsche Hauptstadt Berlin*" and of course not the "*Hauptstadt von Berlin*".
And the United States of America? An altogether different affair because they are just part of (the) America(s)?

Comment: Welcome to ELU.  This is a site for the English language.  There's a stackexchange site for German, and it sounds to me as if your question concerns translation to German.  You might get a better response there.

Comment: This question is legitimate to the point where it concerns understanding the English original. The part about how to express the same in German is off topic.

Answer (score 3):

The decontextualised phrase "*in the southern province of Bumb*a" is ambiguous, resulting from different functions of the preposition *of*.

The phrase could mean that there is an (unnamed) province in the south of Bumba. Or it could mean that Bumba is the name of the southern province.

This second use is a type of apposition*, and in context would most likely be interpreted as such. For example, readers will almost certainly interpret the sentence:

> She lives in the city of Paris

as meaning *She lives in the city named Paris*, and not *She lives in the city that is part of Paris*.

Since, on the other hand, Bumba does not exist either as a province or a country containing a province, the phrase *in the southern province of Bumba* could, out of context, be interpreted either way.

German is off-topic here, so suffice to say that *von* does not play the same dual role, and would be omitted when using an appositional phrase:

> - Sie wohnt in der Hauptstadt Berlin.
> - Das Vereinigte Königreich Großbritannien und Nordirland

* Quirk et al., in section 14.47 of *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* call this special use of **of** *prepositional apposition*. They give the related examples:

> - the fool of a policeman
> - an angel of a girl